# Pass ng-repeat variable to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to pass the `key` value to a javascript function inside an ng-repeat but it's not working

```
<ul class="m-list">
    <li ng-repeat="(key,store) in brand.storesInfo">
            <a onclick="save_key({{ key }})"
                    href="{{ store.url }}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="{{ store.icon }}"/>
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`save_key` it's not an angular controller function

Comment: Hi, could you post also your brand.storesInfo structure?

Comment: The structute is not a problem key an the others values existts and are shown except key

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre] that demonstrates the issue along with a better explanation of expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angularJS you use `ng-click` rather than `onclick` and pass the reference directly rather than interpolated

```
<ul class="m-list">
    <li ng-repeat="(key,store) in brand.storesInfo">
            <a ng-click="save_key(key)"
                    href="{{ store.url }}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="{{ store.icon }}"/>
            </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

As @charlietfl suggests below - if `save_key()` exists outside of the angular app, then you could connect it through the controller with

```
$scope.save_key = save_key
```

This would associate the scoped ng-click function with the page function `function save_key(`...

However, it seems cleaner to me to keep it all in the AJS ecosystem, in which case you would handle all the logic internally with your controller/service etc

```
$scope.save_key = function (key) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Since OP states the function is not a controller function suggest trying `$scope.save_key = save_key`

Comment: @charlietfl - if I understand your comment, would that connect the $scope variable save_key with some outside, non-angular function with the same name? I guess I'd recommend keeping it all in angular though without seeing the structure it's hard to know

Comment: Yes exactly. OP indicated they have an external function. Agree it isn't ideal but suppose it could be from some other code base

Comment: Another way would be adding external function to a service in `run` and injecting service in controller  but that gets more involved and might just get confusing for OP